# Values passed by GET method are forgotten when the form is submitted

Tags: asp.net, html, forms

I'm creating a web system for creating, deleting, voting and viewing online surveys, and I have a problem with a parameter passed in the GET method.

The page `ViewSurvey.aspx` gets a parameter of a survey ID then it then loads the information from the DB and shows it. For example, to view the information about the survey with the ID of `vacations`, we could use: `ViewSurvey.aspx?survey=vacations`.

The page has a form with options of whose votes will be viewed (I.E: by location, age, etc...). But when the form is submitted, the `survey` parameter in the URL is gone.

What can I do to solve it, **OR** what could be another option for passing the survey ID as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a hidden field in the form with a name of 'survey' and initialize it to the value of the request parameter, e.g. 'vacations'.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the QueryString variable using code similar to the c# example below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string surveyType = Page.Request.QueryString["survey"];
}
```

Once you've grabbed the QueryString from the Request object, you can persist it using one of the many options ASP.NET has available (here are some).

```
// Add item to cache
Cache["Survey"] = surveyType;

// Add item to Context
Context.Items["Survey"] = surveyType;

// Add item to ViewState
ViewState["Survey"] = surveyType;
```

Comment: The problem is, the user might change the survey he views. Is there any cache for a single page only?

Comment: If it only deals with the page, you can use the ViewState or a Hidden Field, since the data will reside in the contents of the page.  Cache/Context/Session/etc... can survive past the page.  The benefit to Cache is that it can expire.